# Replace weatherstripping on old Anderson casement windows

Tags: windows

The weatherstripping is damaged or missing on my Anderson casement windows. Not sure of the exact age but they are original and the house was built between 1969-74.

Due to their age, I found replacement parts on a 3rd party website.  They sell the original hard plastic weatherstrip.  http://www.windowparts.com/mobile/Category.aspx?id=221

Should I use the original weatherstrip or would a newer, bulb style weatherstrip a) fit the window and b) make a better seal?